# How to move to check value and move to another state in $stateProvider?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I am working on my AngularUI project. I need to implement some logic before state is loaded and configure on the result to move to another module in another state or to load state in current module.

Here is module definition:

```
angular.module("workPlan", ['damageEvent',
                            'ui.router',
                            'geomindCommon',
                            'templates',
                            'lookups',
                            'ngTouch',
                            'ui.grid',
                            'ui.grid.expandable',
                            'ui.grid.selection',
                            'ui.grid.pinning',
                            'ui.grid.resizeColumns',
                            'ui.bootstrap'
])

.config([
    "$stateProvider",
    "$urlRouterProvider",
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/MainPage");
        $stateProvider
            .state("workPlan", {
                abstract: true,
                url: "/",
                template: "<ui-view></ui-view>"
            })

         .state("workPlan.list", {
             url: "MainPage?myParam",
             templateUrl: "app/workPlan/templates/workPlanList.tmpl.html",
             controller: "workPlanListController",
             controllerAs: "list",
             resolve:{

                 filterParameters: [filterParametersResolver],
                 workPlans: ["workPlanServise", workPlanServiseResolver]
             }
         })
    }
]);
```

At some point if `myParam` value from URL is `true` I need to use this service:

```
$state.go("list.clients");
```

to load list.clients state.

If `myParam` value from URL is `false` I need to load the current state(`workPlan.list`).

But I don't know were to implement the logic to check `myParam`  value and move  or to stay in appropriate state.

I guess it wrong to implement in resolve of the state.

So my question where do I implement described logic above?

Comment: I didn't see a state that is called `list.clients`. Can you post that ?

Answer (score 0):

Define url path instead of query parameter to determine which state to load.

So you can define url like MainPage/work-plan for 'workPlan.list' state and
MainPage/clients for 'list.clients' state.